# Slideshow code doesn't work in Javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging, slideshow

I made a slideshow. This is the HTML code!

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="img/background.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="img/background2.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="img/background3.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
```

and this is the javascript code

```
<script>
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n); 
    }

    function showSlides(slideIndex) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

        if (slideIndex > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1; }
        if (slideIndex < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length; }

        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block"; 
    }
</script>
```

but due to some unknown reasons it doesn't work properly, please debug and explain why this code is not working?

Comment: What debugging have *you* done? Have you at least checked the console for errors?

Comment: I debug it and I think but I am not sure that the bug is the parameter of the function.

Comment: and no errors were shown in console

Comment: How is it behaving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define your index variable twice: `slideIndex`. Once as a global variable and then as a function parameter, overwriting only the function parameter value. You can remove the function parameter and increment / decrease the slideIndex value in your `plusSlides` function.

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides();

function plusSlides(n) {
  slideIndex += n;
    showSlides(); 
}

function showSlides() {

    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

    if (slideIndex > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1; }
    if (slideIndex < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length; }

    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block"; 
}
```